# How does eigenvalues work with binary data in redundancy analysis?

Tags: binary-data, eigenvalues, canonical-correlation

I am using the vegan package in R to do a redundancy analysis ([RDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_statistics), a part of canonical correlation analysis). My response data is binary and my explanatory variables contains 0, 0.5 an 1. I get quite low eigenvalues (~0.05) and my question is how is the binary data affecting the eigenvalue? Will the variability always be 'badly' explained?

Comment: The economic value is not the same as the eigenvalue value. The eigenvalue is a semi major axis length from the hyperellipsoid. You can think of an economic value as a linear model coefficient multiplied by the central value of that term. The PCA tells you where your points are but doesn’t necessarily deal well with variation in density. What that means is a low value for an eigenvalue isn’t necessarily the whole story. It can be small and still strongly meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain if you do some normalization of the variables via scaling them, but it is completely normal to have the canonical variables around the 0.

The variability that they can explain depend on the data itself or the experiment. If the two datasets have low in common the CCA won't be able to explain it, or if it does it will be a false positive.